# java: SAX writer for use in XMLFilter pipeline?

Tags: xml, sax

I'm using an XMLFilter pipeline to get SAX events from an XMLReader, and I would like to put an XMLFilter stage in the pipeline to dump the result to a file, kind of like the "tee" program in unix.

(The XMLReader happens to be [nu.validator.htmlparser.sax.HTMLParser](http://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/apidocs/nu/validator/htmlparser/sax/HtmlParser.html), so there isn't a source XML file, and I care about the XML output of HTMLParser rather than the original HTML file)

First I figured there must be some standard class to do this, but I couldn't find it.

Then I figured I could just write my own subclass of XMLFilterImpl, but I've wasted an hour on this so far, and it's difficult to do all the escaping.

Is there a straightforward way to dump SAX events to an XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/FiltertowriteanXMLdocumentfromaSAXeventstream.htm .

You'd probably prefer something packaged up - sorry, can't put my hands on one immediately.